# Python/Pandas - count last duplicate rows in succession

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have DataFrame like this:

```
        product_id         dt  products_qty
70063      2964562 2017-11-14         0.000
72719      2964562 2017-11-15         2.000
401533     2964562 2017-11-16         0.000
413201     2964562 2017-11-17         0.000
424227     2964562 2017-11-18         0.000
450345     2964733 2017-11-14         4.000
470446     2964733 2017-11-17         0.000
473233     2964733 2017-11-18         0.000
```

And I have to group dataframe by `product_id` column and count last duplicate rows. For example we don't count 70063 row even if it is duplicated with last rows. So the output should be this:

```
  product_id          count
     2964562          3.000
     2964733          2.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#create unique consecutives values by products_qty
a = df['products_qty'].ne(df['products_qty'].shift()).cumsum()
#get lens of each group
b = df.groupby([df['product_id'], a]).size() 
#filter out unique groups and get last row
df = b[b > 1].groupby(level=0).last().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   product_id  count
0     2964562      3
1     2964733      2
```

Detail:

```
print (a)
70063     1
72719     2
401533    3
413201    3
424227    3
450345    4
470446    5
473233    5
Name: products_qty, dtype: int32
```

---

```
print (b)
product_id  products_qty
2964562     1               1
            2               1
            3               3
2964733     4               1
            5               2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: It counts all duplicated rows but I need to count only last duplicated rows

Comment: No, because it count by `a` helper Series - if yes, first value will be `4` not `3`

Comment: When I run this code it shows `4`  next to the `2964562` `product_id`

Comment: It is weird, not understand. Sample is same as in question?

Comment: I add output of `a` and `b`, can you check if same output?

Comment: My sample has 30 days period next to the each product and the last three rows has `0` `products_qty` and this code counts all `0` `products_qty` but not the last three.

Comment: OK, problem is in sample or in real data?

Comment: I think my solution will working with this... Hmmm, so sample working nice ans real data not?

Comment: Didn't check sample but real data not

Comment: I dont understand I check your sample and it return `3`.

Comment: Only there should be problem there are another values with `2965469` in real data. Check it by `df[df['product_id'] == '2965469']`

Comment: Now it works. The problem was in sorting. Thanks a lot :)